# Referencing a Column by Table Header instead of Letter

Tags: excel, vba

I found the following code to hide duplicate rows:

```
For i = Last_Row To First_Row Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F" & First_Row & ":F" & i), Range("F" & i).Value) > 1 Then Rows(i).Hidden = True
Next I
```

The code works great, but I'm using it in a Table so I'd like to replace the fixed column "F" with a table header reference.  That way if someone inserts columns it will still work.  I'm struggling to find the right syntax.

My table and column is:

```
Range("PART_SELECTION_DATABASE[PART '#]")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm whether this is Excel or something else, please

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Find` function to look for the header `PART '#"`.

Once it's found, you can extract the column number using `FindRng.Column`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindHeader()

Dim FindRng As Range
Dim HeadrStr As String
Dim Col As Long

HeadrStr = "PART '#"

Set FindRng = Cells.Find(what:=HeadrStr)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then . make sure Find was successful 
    Col = FindRng.Column ' get the column number
Else ' Find failed to find the Header
    MsgBox "unable to find " & HeadrStr, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

For I = Last_Row To First_Row Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(First_Row, Col), Cells(I, Col)), Cells(I, Col).Value) > 1 Then Rows(I).Hidden = True
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, I had anticipated needing to determine the column number.  I'm using the following:
    Col = Range("PART_SELECTION_DATABASE[PART '#]").Column

It was the usage of cells() that I couldn't get right.  Thanks again!